# "Missing load commands" e-mail when uploading an app with own static framework and bundle

Tags: ios, frameworks

I work on an ObjC framework which we provide to our clients for their own apps. It's a static library which generates .framework files (simulator and iphoneos) which we then lipo create to a fat library. For using CoreData and be compatible with iOS 7, we needed to put the .momd part in a seperate .bundle file which we provide to the client also.

Now when I create a sample Swift app with that framework and bundle, and upload it to the App Store, I get an e-mail after complaining about load commands for the .bundle:

> Missing load commands - The executable at '/Payload/TestSwift.app/TheBundle.bundle/TheBundle' does not have the necessary load commands. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version. If you are using third party development tools, contact the provider.

I have no idea what it wants. Unfortunately I *am* the provider and contacting myself didn't help.

I have googled around and followed the few instructions available:

- [remove generic versioning](https://github.com/UrbanApps/Armchair/issues/24)
- update to latest Xcode (mail)
- upload to app store without Bitcode
- put the framework in Embedded frameworks instead of Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- use the framework in an ObjC app instead

But still the mail comes back with the warning, and the build is not uploaded.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Important note**: I'd like to avoid the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but here's more info:

- we are dropping iOS7 permanently
- with iOS8 it should be possible to create a dynamic .framework file which includes the CoreData directly, removing a .bundle file and easing the process for our client.

Before I dive in, is this an interesting solution? If yes, how does one properly convert a static library to a dynamic library?
Current code within the .framework for loading the .bundle:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TheBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];   
NSString *modelPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"TheCache" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
```

Assumed code if the TheCache schema is within the .framework:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"TheCache" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bizarre issue we just discovered too and it had to do with us building a separate Bundle from the main Static Lib. If you are also building a separate bundle;

- Go to the Bundle's build target
- Do a search within the Build Settings
  for *Versioning*
- Change the *Versioning System* from **Apple    Generic** to **None**

Comment: Unfortunately that was done before, and so for all targets. The error still appears. Are you working with a .framework target or a .a target?

Answer (score 0):

I asked Apple through the Technical Support in Member Center.
The core issue in my case was that my Bundle behaved like an executable, because there were elements in Compile Sources.

Solution:

1. Select your bundle's target
2. Select Build Phases
3. If using CoreData, put YourFile.xcdatamodeld in Copy Bundle Resources (not in Compile Sources like it was in my case)
4. Empty all items of Compile Sources (having elements here implies that the Bundle will be considered as an executable)
5. Run your bundle's target

I suggest to manually delete your previous bundle in your host project prior to copying your newly generated bundle